# Why am I getting a "You are not authorized to access this page." on the Drupal Migrate UI page?

Tags: 8, migrations, upgrading

I just installed this module on my Drupal 8 site hosted locally on Acquia Dev Desktop. I haven't had this issue with any other modules and this is occurring immediately after I install the module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you logged in? Is your login the superuser? You can always get into your local site w/ drush:

```
$ cd /path/to/docroot
$ ../vendor/bin/drush uli --no-browser
http://default/user/reset/1/1527085618/[RANDOM_STRING]/login
```

Assuming your setup uses the drupal-project composer approach. Otherwise, you could use drush w/ a site alias or params.

If you're logged in as the superuser and still have issues, that's indicative of something wrong w/ the routing specification. That shouldn't happen with a contrib module, unless you've made any modifications? If you haven't and the superuser can't access the UI, then I would file an issue w/ the migrate module.

Comment: Wow, I assumed I could use the module if I was logged in as a user with  the Admin role and all the normal Admin permissions but I changed over to the OG admin account and now I can access the page. Thanks!

Comment: You can always add permission to that Admin role for the Migrate permission set, but yeah, typically whenever you enable a new module, you'll need to address its permissions with your set of user roles.

Comment: Unfortunately, there aren't any migrate permissions, or there weren't any after I installed the module.